# Command line with variables in subprocess

Tags: python, variables, subprocess, command

I want to run this command with variables inside a subprocess in a script.

The variable is:

```
filenames[k]
```

`filenames` have many names (strings), which I can go through with `k`.

The command is:

```
python3 train.py "C:\Users\Tommy\data\\"+filenames[k] "C:\Users\Tommy\data\\"+filenames[k]+"_model" --choice A
```

I want to run this command inside a script as subprocess:

```
subprocess.run([" python3 train.py "C:\Users\Tommy\data\\"+filenames[k] "C:\Users\Tommy\data\\"+filenames[k]+"_model" --choice A "])
```

But something is wrong with the syntax. I don't know what.
I run this with Python 3.6.8 on Windows.

Comment: The first argument pass to `run()` should be a list of strings. You can construct this list beforehand. I suggest you do that.

Comment: filenames[1] is data1.csv, this can be format as "C:\Users\Tommy\data\\"+%s % filenames[k]

Comment: @Tommy if you have problem with path formatting use the os.path package  from the standard library os.path.join(...). It is platform independent and (not sure) should escape "strange" characters

Comment: I meant first create an `args` list. i.e.: `args = ['python3', 'train.py',  os.path.join(r'C:\Users\Tommy\data', filenames[k]), os.path.join(r'C:\Users\Tommy\data', filenames[k], "_model"), '--choice A']` and then call `subprocess.run(args)` on a separate line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you get lost with the string concatenation... you have to ways to execute a cmd with `run`or such: either as a string or as a list (as a list is usually more readable!)

Case: `args` as string

```
cmd = f'python3 train.py "C:\Users\Tommy\data\\{filenames[k]}" "C:\Users\Tommy\data\\{filenames[k]}+_model" --choice A'

subprocess.run(args=cmd, shell=True)
```

Case: `args` as list

```
cmd = f'python3 train.py "C:\Users\Tommy\data\\{filenames[k]}" "C:\Users\Tommy\data\\{filenames[k]}+_model" --choice A'

cmd = cmd.split(' ') # provided that no white spaces in the paths!!

subprocess.run(args=cmd, shell=False)
```

**Remark**:

- it is very handy the "new" string concatenation `f"smt {variable} smt else"` where variable is a variable defined before
- if you want that your program will be launched from the shell then you need to add a kwrags parameter `shell=True`, default `False`. In this case, depending if you choose the `args` to be either a string or a list, you should be then more careful: from the docs "if shell is True, it is recommended to pass `args as a string rather than as a sequence"
- Have a look to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), at *Popen Constructor*, for a full description of the signature

Comment: Whether a list is used or not has nothing to do with `shell=True`.

Comment: @martineau Yes, I agree with you but from the docs "if shell is True, it is recommended to pass args as a string rather than as a sequence"... I oversimplify for pedagogical reason

Comment: I don't think the ends justify the means (misinformation) in this case. I also don't recall ever seeing that recommendation in the docs.

Comment: to make matters worse, the "train.py" script that is to be executed expects a path from linux

data/data1.csv

I don't know how the compiler works in Python. Does it just want the syntax for the path to be system conform or does it swallow the change from / (Linux) to \ (Windows) itself?

Comment: @Tommy could you update your answer with your current error?

Comment: Error: [WinError 2] The system can't find the specified file

Comment: try only to print the output of the string. what you get?

Comment: if I use your proposal with "cmd = ..." I get a (unicode error) unicodeescape code can't decode bytes in position...  as an open window SyntaxError in Windows

Comment: ok could you share the string? just `print(cmd)`. It seems that it not anymore about subprocess but just about strings & path formatting. PS in your question there was \\... was an accident or you need to escape it?

Comment: @martineau I did some tests to check the shell=True or False... I found some "contradictory" results. I did file printing some string then I did another file which execute the other file with subprocess. The results I get are: if args is string then shell=True or if args is list then shell=False -> right result. If args is string and shell=False raise exception, if args is list and shell=True doesn't execute the file with the print. Do you know how do you explain this?

Comment: I just try the "args" proposal from @martineau but I change the "python3 train.py..." in "python train.py and now it runs! hmm.... crazy!

Comment: @Tommy using the os.path.join?

Comment: @Tommy ...sorry, but you have also python2 installed?

Comment: No, I have python 3.6.8

Comment: I asked that because if you have installed python 2 and 3 on the same machine then $ python execute python2.7 and $python3 execute python 3. In case you find out if the cause of the problem was either the run or path formatting or shell=True/False or... add it please

Comment: I'll keep testing this until I'm smarter about it too and get back to you....

Comment: I use only python 3.6.8 in virtualenv. Not more.

Comment: Tommy: Only having Python 3 installed is why you didn't need to use `python3` in the command. You also need to specify the paths using the separators appropriate for the OS being used — which is why you need backslashes for them on Windows.

Comment: The division into string sections has helped to make it a bit more manageable.

there are two problems:

1. python3 command not work. Only python command work.
2. (not solved): when passing the files from and to the train.py script, it admits not to have found a file. I'm going to check the problem today.

Comment: The second problem could it be maybe, that I work in a env folder (virtuelenv). If I call the subprocess.run() they dont found the packages of the python? I think the subprocess must call the command from the path inside the env.

Comment: How I can make a pre-subprocess of this command: .\env\Scripts\activate ?`

Comment: @Tommy problem1) when you run python from the shell which command do you perform? python or python3? problem 2) did you try to pass the shell=True of False argument? When I tried with an example I also get a `FileNotFoundError` which I fixed it with such parameter (see my answer). Please edit your answer with your new attempts, start to be difficult to keep track of you did and not